# Выбор одной записи из RethinkDB на Java

Tags: java, rethinkdb

Как можно извлечь одну запись из таблицы RethinkDB на Java? Я попробовал сделать так, как написано в документации:

```
public Object findByObjectUID(String uid) {
        return r.db("dbname").table("tablename")
                .filter(r.hashMap("uid", uid)).run(connection);
    }
```

Но при выполнении получаю ошибку

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rethinkdb.net.Cursor$DefaultCursor
>   cannot be cast to Object

Как правильно это делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы видимо не до конца сделали.

Судя по документации run возвращает именно курсор(`Cursor`). А потом вы фетчите данные с помощью цикла. Так сделано потому, что вернутся может несколько объектов(если поиск не по `primary`)

```
Cursor cursor = r.table("authors").filter(row -> row.g("posts").count().gt(2)).run(conn);
for (Object doc : cursor) {
    System.out.println(doc);
}
```

Или передав вторым аргументом в `run` функцию обработки результата.

Тажке можно использовать `get` в цепочке команд(поиск по primary)

Обратите внимание на [быстрый старт](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/guide/java/)